# How to use a variable variable to focus on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that looks at a popup modal with a form and should get the first input and focus to that. The forms can change and the input id will always be different.

I am catching the id with `var item_id = $('.otf_itm [id]').first().prop('id');` This returns the first. In on case the input has an id of town_name. The problem is that the item does not focus when I use the `$('#' + item_id).focus();` How can I get the form item to focus? I have used this method successfully before to get data using .val() and other manipulate parts of the page

```
// works
$('#town_name').focus();

// doesnt work
$('#' + item_id).focus();
```

Comment: It should work.Whats the value of `item_id`?

Comment: What is `otf_itm [id]` ?

Comment: Are you seriously constructing a jQuery object and searching it for an element, to get that element's ID and create a new jQuery object from it??? Just use the existing object!

Comment: @nietthedarkabsol I dont know what the object will be. There will be a few forms to use this.

Comment: in this case the item_id is 'town_name'

Comment: Just... `$(".otf_itm [id]").first().focus()` should - in theory - work. You have the element, what you're doing is akin to `$("#"+$(this).attr("id"))`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myForm input:first").focus();
```

Will focus the first input element. Whatever the first input element is.

**Remark** `<select>` elements do not fall under this category.

Comment: I cant see any element with `id` as `myForm`

Comment: That's just a generic name I used for "whatever your form is". If OP only has one form on the page, he could use `$("form input:first")`. Since OP didn't specifiy how the form can be found, I couldn't put down the right answer :)

Comment: @Karna since no markup is provided, it seems quite explicit that `myForm` is just a placeholder for the OP's actual form id.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Should you include this in answer instead of just assuming it?

Comment: @flater thanks, I was just way over complicating things there

Comment: @Karna it isn't his answer :)

Comment: @PierceMcGeough: No worries, we all had to learn about things like this at some point :)

Comment: @karna I'd say it's perfectly acceptable since OP hasn't mentioned that he can't change the markup or hinted that there's more than one form on the page so even the generic `form` selector can be used as @Flater has mentioned but that's just my opinion, others might disagree.